# Multiple sites inside one container running Apache : vhost from outside?

Tags: docker, httpd.conf

I would like to run a container with httpd image while hosting multiple websites inside that container. Each website would have a virtual host setup so they can be accessed by a URL from the outside.

Virtual Host configuration inside the container:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
<Directory /var/www/html/public>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dev1.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/dev1
<Directory /var/www/html/public/dev1>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dev2.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public/dev2
<Directory /var/www/html/public/dev2>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to do the setup but all domains from outside always points to the first VirtualHost Block inside the container. It doesn’t get served based on the domain name from outside.

Any help?

Comment: try to follow this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Without using docker, it works. Please check my question above.